# Is there a way to show the Download and Upload speeds in arm as different units?

Tags: nyx

I.e., megabytes per second instead of megabits?
Or, mebibytes/mebibits?
Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the ARM [project page](https://www.atagar.com/arm/), navigate to the Git [repository](https://gitweb.torproject.org/nyx.git/tree/). You'll notice that here ARM is actually referred to as Nyx.

One of the files at the top level of the repository tree is `nyxrc.sample` which provides a sample of different config options that can be set in your `nyxrc` file. (Of course, you don't have a `nyxrc` file, you have an `armrc`. If you've created one.)

The option you want is `features.graph.bw.transferInBytes`. It's set to `False` as default, meaning figures are in bits.